# How do I make a subdomain visible at new URL, as if it is the URL?

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain

I've built a site at subdomain.domain.org using Wordpress with Nixihost. It is done. I'd like to make it visible at www.mynewdomain.com and look like the visitor is at www.mynewdomain.com/page1 not subdomain.domain.org/page1. There should be a way to do this by pointing DNS records, or something? Could you please direct me to the appropriate information/instructions to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have cpanel:

- add your domain as an addon domain
- make the document root of the domain the same directory as where you built subdomain.domain.org
- in the wordpress dashboard change the two URLs to mynewdomain.com